# Collect variables from in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to collect the global ids variables from(R.id) class in an array , how can I do this ?

```
public static final class id {
        public static final int cb_adroite=0x7f0d0058;
        public static final int cb_apple=0x7f0d0055;
        public static final int cb_banana=0x7f0d0057;
        public static final int cb_pear=0x7f0d0056;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about R.id Android class? Because, like the name says, it's a class, not a function nor a method.

If you want to retrieve all id's from the R.id class, you can try this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field[] ID_Fields = R.id.class.getFields();
    int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
            Log.d("FIELDS", ID_Fields[i].getName() + " " + resArray[i]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```